# Bootloader- how to find correct partition?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bootloader

im writing a bootloader that looks for stage2 in FAT32.
I have almost all the code working but for one thing - finding the correct partition or rather sector offset of my partition

the BIOS is kind enough to provide us with the drive number we were loaded from :

```
mov [_BOOTDRIVE], dl
```

however is there any way to get the sector of the partition we were loaded off from or does it have to be hardcoded some way ?

Comment: Don't think that is provided. You can read the MBR and check which partition is marked active. Or, as you say, hardcode the partition when the boot sector is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the MBR bootsector loads and executes the partition bootsector, it loads DL with the drive number and DS:SI with a pointer the entry in the partition table for the selected partition. Your bootloader can read that entry to determine the location of it's partition.

Comment: Just as I coded the MBR parsing :) Ah, well it seems to be different on different BIOSes anyway and id need to depend on the MBR Loader not changing those registers..

Comment: @n00b The BIOS doesn't know anything about MBR partition tables, so it doesn't load DS:SI, it just sets DL. It's the code in the MBR itself that interprets the partition table, loads your bootloader, sets DS:SI and then jumps to your code. Note that "multiboot" MBRs, ones that let you choose which partition to boot off of, may also allow booting off other drives, so the DL value passed to your code could be different than one passed to the MBR by the BIOS. You don't have to worry about DL and DS:SI referring to anything other than the drive and partition your bootloader was loaded from.